Next.js 15 dynamic page is cached without using any caching
I have upgraded a simple website to Next.js 15.0.1 with some static pages. But when working on my blog post page it shows that the route is static with the following code:
import SectionWrapper from "@/components/shared/section-wrapper";

export default async function BlogPage() {
  const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts").then((res) =>
    res.json(),
  );
  const posts = response.posts;

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-3">
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div
          key={post.id}
          className="flex flex-col gap-3 rounded border bg-card p-4"
        >
          <div>
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold">{post.title}</h2>
            <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">{post.body}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

I thought caching is now something opt-in when using an await in my server component? I can force it to be dynamic by calling await cookies(); but that's the old way, I don't want that... I know I can use export const dynamic = ... but the point is that I thought Next.js 15 doesn't need this when using an await in my component.
It shows as Static route on the webpage and when building it also says static

await enforces the component to be a React Server Component (or will lead to an Error if used in a non-server-component context). But apart from that, I never heard that await has any effect on caching. Wouldn't know why it should, either - Next.js assumes that every request against the /posts endpoint bears the same result since no varying parameters are used in that request, and therefore it relies on the cached result the next time.
Another way to prevent fetch from caching the result:
fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts", {cache: 'no-store'})

(See here for details on that.)
Edit to address some confusion:
In Next.js 15, fetch calls in GET route handlers default to {cache: 'no-store'} (src). But this is not the case for a React Server Component, where you still have to set that on your own.

The default behaviour of the fetch should be no-store in Next.js 15 now

@SiebeBaree The opposite claimed in the documentation. Maybe you are refering to GET Route Handlers? What you've created isn't a route handler though (in other words, no GET endpoint in api/), but a React Server Component.

Also note that will now set a no-store default to the fetch cache (https://nextjs.org/blog/next-15#other-changes force-dynamic) - in case you're wondering about that behavior other places where you're actually using an route handler.


If you are not using any Dynamic APIs anywhere else in this route, it will be prerendered during next build to a static page. The data can then be updated using Incremental Static Regeneration.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-the-fetch-api
Dynamic APIs:

cookies
headers
connection
draftMode
searchParam prop
unstable_noStore
unstable_after

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-apis
So when you build this all posts from the https://dummyjson.com/posts endpoint will be prefetched and prerendered. This will be cached so rendering your component will be instantaneous thats why its static. After 60 seconds cache will be revalidated.
Nextjs has an example here.

this code is fine in development but not during build. i dont know how you managed to build it since build will prerender it. as far as i know fetch will fail during prerender since there is no server running during static generation. in any case the build fails just make your page dynamic.

im stoopid i thought you were fetching on localhost:3000. in this case you are fetching from https://dummyjson.com/posts which build will prefetch and will work because its available via http. thats why its static
